# Use Console-App to host ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, webforms

I´ve made an C# Windows Forms-App (.NET Framework) and realized i want a Web UI instead of WinForms. So i rewrote my Application in in ASP.NET.

The ASP.NET Application works the same as the WinForms. Now i would like to share my ASP.NET App like a WinForms which you technically can run on any other computer. It should be runnable like an normal .exe App which just directs you to localhost with an own port for the UI.

I thought about it and researched a bit. I think i need a Console App which runs a local WebServer which uses my ASP.NET site. But i reached the limit of my skills. I dont know how i would make this. I would appreciate any push in the right direction.

Comment: have you seen web installer ?

Comment: Possible you could use Kestrel, though it would mean porting your app to .NET Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel